# Elasticbeanstalk giving health check errors

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, nestjs, aws-cdk

I keep getting the below error when I deploy my backend (NestJS) to the elasticbeanstalk. I am new to AWS, can any tell me what this error entails ? I have a health endpoint set up in my backend.

```
*1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.0.74.74, server: , request: "GET /health HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/health", host: "10.0.87.89"
```

I get a `503 Service Unavailable: Back-end server is at capacity`.
My backend shows that has successfully started at port 8080

Comment: Have you updated the ElasticBeanstalk health check path?

Comment: @j-petty Yes, I have updated the health check path in EB, but I think I see the issue (but not sure), when I am running the app locally and try to access /health, it gives me `{"statusCode":401,"message":"Unauthorized"}` which makes me think that it is not accessible. Not sure why it is not, but let me try working that out first I guess.

Comment: Also, when I try to access the instance behind the load balancer, for example say the ip address is "50.0.87.89" or whatever, I does bring up my backend, which means that my backend is rooted properly. But out of curiosity, I would sure like to know why the health check endpoint would affect the load balancer ? does it only want to access healthy instances ?

Comment: The load balancer will use the health check and try to route traffic to healthy instances. But yes it sounds like you health check service is protected by authentication. You'll need to make the endpoint anonymously accessible. If you share the code where you define your health check endpoint I can help identify the problem.